# git clone is not cloning an existing remote repository

Tags: git, github, https, terminal, clone

I am trying to clone a from a remote repository on Github to work on a code.

The command I am using is:

```
git clone https://github.com/appbrewery/Todoey-iOS13.git
```

And the error I am getting is:

> remote: Repository not found.

> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Lev0071/Story.git/' not found

[Output on Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHjlg.png)

Why is git telling me about

> https://github.com/Lev0071/Story.git/

Whilst Im trying to clone

> https://github.com/appbrewery/Todoey-iOS13.git

How do I command my git to quit obsessing about "https://github.com/Lev0071/Story.git/" ?

Thanks

Comment: Comment SuperHarmony910, Thank you for the suggestion that is one possibility, i was embarking on the path you suggested. It makes sense reinstall and restart. I needed to install HomeBrew on my Mac to install the software you provided. I realised the command to install HomeBrew also failed giving the same error message ('@Lev007'). I decided to reset my .gitconfig file using "rm ~/.gitconfig" and Violla!

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be Git tracking your profile for the repository, as your tag is '@Lev007'; as a makeshift (or permanent if preferable), try using the new [GitHub CLI (macOS installation)](https://github.com/cli/cli#macos) to clone this repository, it may solve your problem!

Comment: Thank you, I have found the solution whilst following your recommendation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, after not being able to install [GitHub CLI(macOS Version)](https://github.com/cli/cli#macos) and getting the exact same error shown in the original question.

The solution I found was to reset my git configuration file using:

```
rm ~/.gitconfig
```

Thank you so much **SuperHarmony910** you did set off the process of finding the solution. :)